How can I configure mule standalone so that it picks up property files from MULE_HOME/lib/user?
Where can I configure mule standalone v 4.6.2, so that deployed apps will fetch property files from MULE_HOME/lib/user folder rather than the project folder src/main/resources
In the global elements I would define these
<global-property doc:name="Global Property" doc:id="bce2118a-923f-49c6-96e8-0eea496a0a12" name="mule.env" value="dev" />
    <configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" doc:id="f66c26b0-f63c-4176-bdaa-ceb79f352062" file="${mule.env}-properties.yaml" />

And place dev-properties.yaml in MULE_HOME/lib/user and remove it from the project src/main/resources folder.
This works in older version 4.5.3. But I don't know where it is actually configured to allow such behavior.

Have you tested if it works on Mule 4.6?

And why do you want to use that directory specifically?

I have not tested with 4.6. If I have to test it, I will test with 4.6.3 as its the latest.

It would be expected that you tested before making the question. At this time the latest Mule 4.6 release is 4.6.4 (June 2024 patch release). See release notes for the latest: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-esb

No specific reason for using that particular location now that you ask. Its simply because it's the location we used in 4.5.3. I have little say in the matter and I am not even admin that set the servers up. I am only trying to find solution so that I can give it to admin team.

I did a test on 4.6.4. The result is same. It's still not able to pick up yaml files from $MULE_HOME/lib/user.

It turned out to be a bug in the mule runtime.
Mule Runtime is unable to find properties files at $MULE_HOME/lib/user

The mule runtime uses the Tanuki Software java service wrapper to initialize the JVM.
You can add a path to the classpath in the $MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf file by using the wrapper.java.classpath.<n> properties.
Then you can reference properties files in that folder like so:
<configuration-properties file="classpath://${mule.env}-properties.yaml" />


I tried doing that. But it didn't work. wrapper.java.classpath.2=%MULE_HOME%/lib/user

In the question, I see you put the path as file="${mule.env}-properties.yaml", but you need to use the prefix classpath:// .  I will update my answer
